# Does the time of day affect fuel economy?

Tags: road-vehicles, fossil-fuel

One tip that I heard as a young driver was something along the following:

> Try to refuel in the early morning or in the evening as the denser gas
>   will get you better fuel economy.

Since then I have seen the same advice or question appear online from [time](http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20061208112438AAf4N76) to [time](http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/non_aviation/read.main/619333/). As such, I have been wondering, does the time of day that you refuel have a meaningful (even if over the long run) impact on a vehicle's fuel economy?

Comment: Temperature affects the density of the fuel; which matters in places that sell fuel by volume. There is such a thing as mass flow meters, but they are not used in many countries.

Comment: It's an odd phrasing of the claim; I suspect you misunderstood. I've heard it as you will get more fuel mass per litre, so the fuel is cheaper $/kg. But that's not related to fuel economy.

Comment: @Oddthinking - I thought that as well, but generally I've heard it in conversations about fuel economy with the explanation that denser fuel allows you to travel farther between refueling as opposed to fuel that is warmer when you refuel.

Comment: @Robz: Traveling further between refueling also has nothing to do with fuel economy. That's just a restatement of what Oddthinking said--temperature affects fuel density.

Comment: If be fuel economy you mean currency/distance (or the inverse, of course) or volume/distance then it does matter. Of course mass/distance makes more sense. Of course, the conventional units used in the US and Europe are both in terms of distance and volume.

Comment: @dmckee: That's not "fuel economy," though... that's just plain "economy." :)

Comment: @Rob: Are you are implying that - once purchased it the morning - the fuel retains its higher density in the car throughout the day?

Comment: @Oddthinking - That's what I've heard even though for obvious reasons I know it to not be true. The basic logic that I've heard is that higher denser fuel at time of purchase = better fuel economy.

Comment: @dmckee - I believe that the currency/distance model is what is at the heart of the claim.

Comment: Given that on the gas stations tanks are deep underground, I really doubt that the temperature would vary much during a day.

Comment: Liquid density does not vary much by temperature so "gas" which is a liquid (countries outside the USA would call it petrol or something less confusing) won't vary enough to notice (especially from underground tanks where the temperature won't change much with the air temperature). What might vary with time of day is traffic speed which will have a **very large** effect on fuel economy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can expect a density change of 0.7 g/l/Degree:

[image]

> Density of fuels in g/l with respect to temperature; red curves represent the tolerance band for gasoline; blue curves represent the tolerance band for diesel fuel and the pink curve represents the density of pure ethanol

[Source](http://www.petrolplaza.com/technology/articles/MiZlbiYxMTA1NyYmMSYyJiY=)

So, if you consider a temperature span of 20 C during the day, your density variation will be near 15 g/l (or 2% = 15/700) ...

**Edit**

Two interesting related articles:

[Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/inboxer/household/gastips.asp): Tips help consumers get the most from their gasoline dollar

[LA Times](http://articles.latimes.com/2007/aug/22/autos/hy-wheels22): As temperatures rise in underground storage tanks, gasoline loses energy, but fuel prices don't flex to compensate consumers

Comment: 15g per litre is more than I would expect - with a 50 l tank is gives you almost a litre for free. However: 20 deg difference is quite lot, and moreover, this assumes the fuel temperature will differ that much as well. Given fuel tanks are usually underground, I am afraid the real difference will be much smaller.

Comment: @Suma There are also a lot of other factors to consider. For example, the fuel is usually transported (in my country by truck) to the gas station. Thermal equilibrium after loading the gas station tanks may take quite a while

Comment: @Suma - Depending upon the time of year and where you live I could see there being a 20 degree difference (Fahrenheit) over the course of the day.

Comment: @RobZ 20 deg F would be only 11 deg C. 20 deg C is possible, but very unusual in normal inhabited areas. That said, I consider the second part of the argument (underground tanks) more important.

Comment: Even if the air temperature were going through 20° swings, I would not expect the temperature of the fuel stored in underground tanks to very anywhere near as much.

Answer (score 2):

In Canada fuel prices are by law corrected for this effect. Here is what the [Consumers Council of Canada says](http://www.consumerscouncil.com/index.cfm?PAGEPATH=&ID=13906#temperature):

> Gasoline, like everything else, expands as it gets warmer and
>   contracts as it gets colder.  Without temperature correction, a litre
>   of gasoline on a warm day would contain less gasoline by weight than
>   on a cold day.  Gasoline is sold by volume but what you are actually
>   paying for is the energy to make your car go.  Temperature correction
>   ensures that, regardless of temperature, you receive the same amount
>   of energy for your purchase although the volume may differ.
>   Measurement Canada, an agency of Industry Canada, regulates
>   measurement of gasoline at the pump.

Comment: Thus getting around the problem of already having a bjillion (well, at least 100 because this is Canada...) volumetric flow meters already installed.

Comment: Does my Mum's family being from BC allow me to make that kind of joke?

Comment: No problem. Everyone knows we only use gasoline to heat our igloos anyway.